# Passing and updating a structural array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, reference

So I'm having some trouble with my program. It doesn't seem to fill the array properly. It dosen't seem to populate pass element 0, even though I'm increasing i. When I debug and go back, i remains zero. Should I be doing something different? I feel like I'm passing or updating the array improperly. Can't really use any STL libraries. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
struct Client
{
string name;
string zip;
double balance;
};

Client bAccounts [30]; //structural array in main()

int addClnt(Client(&bAccounts)[30], int); //prototype
int addClnt(Client(&bAccounts)[30], int clientCount) //function to add 
elements

{

cout << "Enter Account Name:" << endl;
cin >> bAccounts[i].name;

cout << "Enter Account Zip:" << endl;
cin >> bAccounts[i].zip;

cout << "Enter Account Balance:" << endl;
cin >> bAccounts[i].balance;


cout << "Enter Last Transaction" << endl;
cin >> bAccounts[i].lastTrans;

clientCount++; //to return number of clients added
i++; //to populate different element of array on next call of function.

return clientCount + 1;
```

}

So I added + 1 to return clientCount and then set i = clientCount. However, clientCount remains at zero and dosen't update.

Comment: You can step through your code with a debugger, and look at the various variables to see where things go wrong. If that doesn't help, edit your question to include (properly formatted) a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Phil. I removed some of the unneeded code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the array doesn't have any values after the first one is because you never reach passed the first element. You increment `i` at the end of the function, but at the top of your `addClnt` function, `i` is set back to `0` . This will just keep resulting on overwriting the old previous data

EDIT:

```
#include <iostream>

//use pass by reference (&)
void add_client(int& index_loc){

    //do whatever

    //this changes the actual value passed into the function 
    index_loc++;

}

int main(){

    int loc = 0;

    add_client(loc);
    add_client(loc);
    add_client(loc);

    //outputs 3 
    std::cout << "current #: " <<  loc << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Is there anyway for i to keep it's value or do I need some sort of loop? I only want to ask for data once and then exit the function.

Comment: you can pass the index location on which you want to add the values

Comment: That makes sense. So I added + 1 to return clientCount and then set i = clientCount. However, clientCount remains at zero and dosen't update.

Comment: Thanks so much, you really helped me. I sincerely appreciate the help. I wasn't thinking and missed the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

clientCount is only getting incremented in that functions scope. When that function goes to it's return statement, all variables and all the work it did has completely died.

You are passing clientCount by value and not by reference, so clientCount will always be 0, and incrementing it inside that local function won't actually change clientCount's value *outside* of the function.

What you need to do is pass it by reference.

EDIT: The chosen answer does not explain why his solution works. The answer provided is incorrect.

The reason why the code works because again, you pass by reference and not by value.